# User group is not creating?

Tags: django, user-permissions, usergroups

Here I made a form for taking the group name from the user and then tried to create group name with that name entered by user but it is not giving me the expected result.It is neither throwing any error nor saving the data in the database.
When i used `group_name = request.POST['name']` instead of `cleaned_data` it throws:

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'name'
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

forms.py

```
class AddUserGroupForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
def add_user_groups(request):
    form = AddUserGroupForm()
    #group_name = request.POST['name']
    #print(group_name,'group_name')
    if form.is_valid():
        group_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        permissions = request.POST.getlist('user_permissions')
        new_group = Group.objects.create(name=group_name)
        new_group.permissions.add(permissions)
        messages.success(request,'New group added.')
        return redirect('organization:view_groups')
    return render(request,'organization/add_user_groups.html',{'user_permissions':user_permissions,'form':form})
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'organization:add_user_group' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
    <label> Group Name : </label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Enter 
            group name" name="name">
                    <label>Permissions:</label>
                    {% for permission in user_permissions %}
                        <input name="user_permissions" type="checkbox" id="permission-{{permission.id}}"
                          value="{{permission.id}}">
                        <label for="permission-{{permission.id}}"> {{permission.name}}</label>


                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}                               
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
         </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your cleaned_data is empty for
`form = AddUserGroupForm()` if you want to access the data

do `form = AddUserGroupForm(request.POST)`

so that data will  be *cleaned* according to `POST` request and call `is_valid()` on  it.

If you wish add validation add it in `clean` method of form class see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/)

It should be like this

```
def add_user_groups(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddUserGroupForm(request.POST)
    #group_name = request.POST['name']
    #print(group_name,'group_name')
    if form.is_valid():
        group_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        permissions = request.POST.getlist('user_permissions')
        new_group = Group.objects.create(name=group_name)
        new_group.permissions.add(permissions)
        messages.success(request,'New group added.')
        return redirect('organization:view_groups')
  else:
        #empty form for get request
        form = AddUserGroupForm()
  return render(request,'organization/add_user_groups.html',{'user_permissions':user_permissions,'form':form})
```

Comment: now i got problem while adding permissions to the group it is throwing `unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: which line you are getting this ?

Comment: `new_group.permissions.add(permissions)` here

Comment: First create permission by `Permission.objects.create()` from the list you are getting then add the permission it should be `Permission` instance

Comment: `new_group.permissions.set(permissions)` worked instead of `add`